# Providing function() from Application to Library

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have a Class AppComponent in my Application that has this function

```
scan(){
  var success = function(result) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(result.text, undefined, 2));
    }
  var failure = function(result) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(result.text, undefined, 2));
    }
  cordova.plugins.BarcodeScanner.scan(success, failure, [])
}
```

My Libarary provides the Pages for my Application but i cannot add this function inside the Library, because not every User of it needs the Barcode scanner.

My Question, how can i Dependency Inject this function on a non essential basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance of a Service and provide the function, a value or an instance of an Object.

```
this.deviceSer.injectFunction(myFunction)
this.deviceSer.setEnvironment('app')
this.deviceSer.Keyboard = Keyboard
```

and add the Service und public-api.ts as export

```
export { DeviceService } from './lib/services/load-deviceinfo/device.service'
```